# Connecting CRM Online to an external SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, security, dynamics-crm

My customer wants to connect a Dynamics CRM Online account to an external Office 365 SharePoint account.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

In order to configure it, you need to:

1. Assign user permissions to the Team SharePoint site
2. Configure CRM Online for SharePoint document management
3. Enable Server-based SharePoint Integration 
   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863709.aspx

He can also integrate it with other Office 365 services, such as Exchange Online and Skype for Business. Reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863703.aspx

The integration will allow for SSO (single sign-on) and he will use only one set of credentials everywhere: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh670607.aspx

Bear in mind that, *after you enable server-based SharePoint integration, you can’t revert to the previous client-based authentication method.*

Check out also the following video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4MwmqMvM3s&feature=youtu.be&list=PLRvH_Jgj96NlwUAfum-44sfNjsuWCeNkV